# App using ArcGis Engine throws error at customers

Tags: arcgis-engine

I developed a program using the ArcGIS Engine 10.0. On my development computer it runs nicely, but when I deploy the binary to the customer computer the program throws an exception when trying to initialize the license.

The exception: "*ArcGIS version not specified. You must call RuntimeManager.Bind before creating any ArcGIS components.*"

This error does show after I called RuntimeManager.Bind, and I'm quite sure I did not accidentially instanciate any other ArcGIS objects before calling RuntimeManager.Bind.

How can I find the source of this problem? Why does it only show up at the customer?

The code I'm using to initialise:

```
ESRI::ArcGIS::RuntimeManager::Bind(ESRI::ArcGIS::ProductCode::Engine);
ESRI::ArcGIS::esriSystem::AoInitialize^  aoi = gcnew ESRI::ArcGIS::esriSystem::AoInitializeClass();

ESRI::ArcGIS::esriSystem::esriLicenseProductCode productCode = ESRI::ArcGIS::esriSystem::esriLicenseProductCode::esriLicenseProductCodeEngine;
if (aoi->IsProductCodeAvailable(productCode) == ESRI::ArcGIS::esriSystem::esriLicenseStatus::esriLicenseAvailable)
{
  aoi->Initialize(productCode);
}
```

Comment: Have you deployed the runtime on client's machine? You might also want to look at the [online help] (http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002ns000000)

Comment: Interesting comment in [Esri's blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisdesktop/archive/2010/07/19/Bind-and-License-your-standalone-ArcGIS-Engine-or-Desktop-application.aspx) about Bind returning a void.  Are you calling Bind in a try/catch?

Comment: Am calling the whole init in a try catch. I will check the result of bind, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the client have ArcGIS 10?
Maybe you're trying to bind a Runtime product when the client has desktop installed? Do you use the RuntimeManager::InstalledRuntimes property to determine which product to bind?

Comment: Great idea, I'll check the InstalledRuntimes!

Comment: You hit gold! The client had desktop installed, and the ESRI support #1 told me there is no difference while #2 told me "well, they might need to be initialized differently, using a different bind or product".
Now am checking with the customer how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I would check to see what license the customer's computers runs. I would run ArcGIS Administrator on both machines and compare the licenses installed.